# set of layouts for activity with multiple buttons and views

Tags: android, button, layout, view

I want to create an activity composed by many buttons and edittexts.
I have a first row with 5 buttons (equispaced and of the same dimension),
a second row with two buttons (1/4 and 3/4 are the relative dimensions)
and a third row (the largest one) which is divided into two columns:
on the left I just add programmatically some editexts, on the right
I have three big buttons. Which set of layouts should I use to create such an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a linearlayout, since with these you can get your first two rows fairly easily.

Something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```